# how to disable fancybox on certain div's

Tags: php, fancybox

I have a fancybox that opens on div click. The divs are made automatically and the id's are not the same. 
I have 8 divs on which the fancybox should open on 4 of them and it does. 
But on the others, it opens also with a content can't be found message, and that should not pop up.

I have tried the jquery removeclass function already but doesn't seem to be working.
 This is the code :

```
$outputEdities =     '<div id="data_' . $currID . '" class="fancybox-content" style="display: none; max-width: 600px;"> ';

                while($rowEditie = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultEdities)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results

                    $currIDEditie = $rowEditie['id'];
                    $currStream = $rowEditie['streamurl'];
                    $currStation = $rowEditie['stationid'];
                    $currName = $rowEditie['editienaam'];



                    $outputEdities .=    '<h2>Editie</h2>';
                    $outputEdities .=    '<h1><a href="'. $currStream . '" id="' . $currIDEditie . '" class="editieClick" alt="' . $currStream . '">'. $currName .' </a></h1>'; 

                }

                $outputEdities .=    '</div>';


            }

            $output .= '<div class="content-b' . $count . '" style="text-align:center;">';
            //$output .= $outputEdities;
            $output .= '<a href="#" alt="' . $currName . ' Luisteren" id="' . $currID . '"  data-fancybox data-src="#data_' . $currID . '" href="javascript:;"><img src="' . $currPicture . '" alt="' . $currName . ' Luisteren" /></a>';
            $output .= $outputEdities;
            $output .= '</div>';



            if( $count == 1 )
                $count = 2;
            else if( $count == 2 )
                $count = 3;
            else if( $count == 3 )
            {
                $count = 1;
                $output .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
```

This code generates the divs and shows content.

I dont know if I have posted my question correctly but we will see.

Comment: Why you simply do not apply that classname to elements that do not need to start fancybox?

Comment: Oh, you are using v3, therefore you need to remove `data-fancybox` attribute to disable fancybox.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: But what did you expect? You have to decide by yourself what do you want to do.

Comment: :D Just think logically, you simply have to set `data-fancybox` attribute for elements that should start fancybox OR set that attribute for all elements and then remove where fancybox is not needed. Right?

Comment: yes but all the divs are already created with unique id's and i dont get how i can disable them on the ones i dont want it to be on

Comment: 1) "i dont get how i can disable" - I already explained multiple times, remove `data-fancybox` attribute; 2) " on the ones i dont want it to be on" - read some basic tutorial about jQuery, for example, this one https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ (you  can do that without jQuery, too - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute )